# How to override fillOval function in Java?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, graphics, paintcomponent

The issue I am having is that I want to fill an oval, but I am using floats as my 'x' and 'y' values. Here is what I have:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
.
.
.
for(Coordinates cord : tempVertices)
{
    g.fillOval(cord.x,cord.y,DIAMETER,DIAMETER);
}
// DIAMETER = 10

// Coordinate Class is just a variable with an 'x' and 'y' value stored in floats
// Floats range from 0 to 1, so type casting won't work...

// tempVertices is just an ArrayList with Coordinates values
```

I am using NetBeans IDE 7.2 and I don't know how to override the `fillOval` method, and I cannot use an import from : `import org.newdawn.slick.*;` (It wouldn't recognize it). Is there a better `Graphics` option or easier way to achieve this simple `fillOval`?

Comment: What is `g` ? Looks like you want to override "someone else's" code?

Comment: this is in a overloaded paintComponent(Graphics g) function...

Comment: Can you just cast your floats to ints? `g.fillOval((int)(coord.x), (int)(coord.y)...`

Comment: No, they range from 0 to 1, so they will all be truncated to 0, unless they are 1 of course.

Comment: `Graphics` deals with pixels on a discrete canvas. Unless you're trying to position ovals ellipses at fractional pixels for some reason, you'll have to explicitly convert the 0..1 range to absolute coordinates. Unfortunately you haven't really explained what you want to be drawn in the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be looking for the `fill()` method of `Graphics2D`, which accepts any `Shape`:

```
g.fill(new Ellipse2D.Float(cord.x, cord.y, DIAMETER, DIAMETER));
```

You'll also want to explore any supported `java.awt.RenderingHints`.